# Mysql query completing but returning as an error due to null that appears at the end of the query

Tags: php, mysql, database, slim

Okay, so We have an issue with a slim php application we use in our api for organizations. When we post an update query to the slim application  the data passes through.

The problem is that even though the data passes through to the api and the operation is performed on all the fields. It returns as an error. This is because the when we run the function it's corresponding sql query at the end of the SQL query right smack dab in the where statement right next to the variable from the function call in this format WHERE id=$idnull. With $id being the actual value. The function is structured the same way as our succesfully functiong venue methods. Does anyone have any ideas?

At my wits end trying to resolve this so functions writing to our database for organizations function properly.

```
function updateOrg($id) {
error_log('addOrg\n', 3, 'php.log');
$request = Slim::getInstance()->request();
$body = $request->getBody();
//var_dump($body);
$org = json_decode($body);

// Handle Checkboxes
if(isset($_REQUEST['recAddEnable'])){ $rAdde = 1; } else $rAdde = 0;
if(isset($_REQUEST['recTelEnable'])){ $rTele = 1; } else $rTele = 0;
if(isset($_REQUEST['recUrlEnable'])){ $rUrle = 1; } else $rUrle = 0;

$sql = "UPDATE usg_usg_orgs 
        SET 
            oname='$_REQUEST[oname]', 
            oemail='$_REQUEST[oemail]', 
            odesc='$_REQUEST[odesc]', 
            ourl='$_REQUEST[ourl]', 
            oadd1='$_REQUEST[oadd1]', 
            oadd2='$_REQUEST[oadd2]', 
            ozip='$_REQUEST[ozip]', 
            ocity ='$_REQUEST[ocity]',
            ostate ='$_REQUEST[ostate]', 
            otel ='$_REQUEST[otel]',
            ofax ='$_REQUEST[ofax]', 
            recTel ='$_REQUEST[recTel]', 
            recTelEnable= $rTele, 
            recAdd1='$_REQUEST[recAdd1]',
            recAdd2='$_REQUEST[recAdd2]',
            recAddEnable= $rAdde,
            recCity='$_REQUEST[recCity]', 
            recCounty='$_REQUEST[recCounty]', 
            recUrl='$_REQUEST[recUrl]', 
            recUrlEnable=$rUrle, 
            recState='$_REQUEST[recState]',
            recZip='$_REQUEST[recZip]',
            recPubNote='$_REQUEST[recPubNote]',
            recPrivNote='$_REQUEST[recPrivNote]', 
            priContact='$_REQUEST[priContact]', 
            priTitle='$_REQUEST[priTitle]', 
            priPhone='$_REQUEST[priPhone]',
            priCell='$_REQUEST[priCell]',
            priEmail='$_REQUEST[priEmail]',
            secContact='$_REQUEST[secContact]',
            secTitle='$_REQUEST[secTitle]', 
            secPhone='$_REQUEST[secPhone]',
            secCell='$_REQUEST[secCell]',
            secEmail='$_REQUEST[secEmail]',
            addContact='$_REQUEST[addContact]', 
            addTitle='$_REQUEST[addTitle]',
            addPhone='$_REQUEST[addPhone]',
            addCell='$_REQUEST[addCell]',
            addEmail='$_REQUEST[addEmail]',
            invContact='$_REQUEST[invContact]',
            invTitle='$_REQUEST[invTitle]', 
            invPhone='$_REQUEST[invPhone]',
            invCell='$_REQUEST[invCell]',
            invEmail='$_REQUEST[invEmail]', 
            recModified = UNIX_TIMESTAMP() 
        WHERE oid= $id";
        echo $sql;
try {
    $db = getConnection();
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);  
    $stmt->execute();
    $db = null;
    echo json_encode($org); 
} catch(PDOException $e) {

    echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';

}
```

}

This is the function we use to write to orgs.

Below is the function we use to write to the api to write orgs.

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "//usasportgroup.com/api3/orgs/update/"+oid,
        data: {     
        oname:jQuery('#onameMF').val(),
        oadd1:jQuery('#oadd1MF').val(),
        oadd2:jQuery('#oadd2MF').val(),
        otel:jQuery('#otelMF').val(),
        ocity:jQuery('#ocityMF').val(),
        ostate:jQuery('#ostateMF').val(),
        ozip:jQuery('#ozipMF').val(),
        ourl:jQuery('#ourlMF').val(),
        oemail:jQuery('#oemailMF').val(),
        recAdd1:jQuery('#recAdd1MF').val(),
        recAdd2:jQuery('#recAdd2MF').val(),
        recAddEnable:jQuery('#recAddEnableMF').val(),
        recTel:jQuery('#recTelMF').val(),
        recTelEnable:jQuery('#recTelEnableMF').val(),
        recZip:jQuery('#recZipMF').val(),
        recCity:jQuery('#recCityMF').val(),
        recState:jQuery('#recStateMF').val(),
        recUrl:jQuery('#recUrlMF').val(),
        recUrlEnable:jQuery('#recUrlEnableMF').val(),
        recPubNote:jQuery('#recPubNoteMF').val(),
        priContact:jQuery('#priContactMF').val(),
        priTitle:jQuery('#priTitleMF').val(),
        priPhone:jQuery('#priPhoneMF').val(),
        priEmail:jQuery('#priEmailMF').val(),
        priCell:jQuery('#priCellMF').val(),
        secContact:jQuery('#secContactMF').val(),
        secTitle:jQuery('#secTitleMF').val(),
        secPhone:jQuery('#secPhoneMF').val(),
        secEmail:jQuery('#secEmailMF').val(),
        secCell:jQuery('#secCellMF').val(),
        invContact:jQuery('#invContactMF').val(),
        invTitle:jQuery('#invTitleMF').val(),
        invPhone:jQuery('#invPhoneMF').val(),
        invEmail:jQuery('#invEmailMF').val(),
        invCell:jQuery('#invCellMF').val(),
        addContact:jQuery('#addContactMF').val(),
        addTitle:jQuery('#addTitleMF').val(),
        addPhone:jQuery('#addPhoneMF').val(),
        addEmail:jQuery('#addEmailMF').val(),
        addCell:jQuery('#addCellMF').val()},
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
        jQuery('#orgModal').modal('hide');
        },
        error: function(data) {     
        console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

This is where how we get the ID:

```
$app->post('/update/:id', 'updateOrg');
```

As stated in the comment chain below
This is an example of what we return from our error function WHERE oid= 1216null

Anyone have any ideas? Anyone? This has been plaguing us since we first built the system.

I think it might be server side because the ID goes through and is used but at the end of the statement there's a null that is not attached to the number. I've checked.
Before you ask bound parameters are a long term goal.
Upon further inspection it seems that it returns a statusText of Okay. with a status of 200.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: would u please be so kind to prepare your query/parts of your code?

Comment: where's your code? (not a screenshot of the code)

Comment: Guys I have now edited my comment to include the function I am attempting to debug. As I have said the Code is similar to an existing and working function that looks the same. for venues

Comment: Congratulations: your query is vulnerable to [SQL-injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_injection).

Comment: Since your error starts at "Where ID=$id"  `UNIX_TIMESTAMP() ` is the only thing in your whole update statement that's not in single quotation. maybe it could be that? im not sure... i can't spot any other error atm.

Comment: This is an example of what we return from our error function WHERE oid= 1216null

Comment: so basically the value from  $ID is 1216   but at the same time puts a null behind the $id?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what happens. It doesn't happen in the venue function that uses the same structure but here it does.

Comment: One thing i want to know tho. Where is your $ID getting the value? i know its not in the function you have here, so i assume it's getting it from a post or get method? can you put that code in as well if posible?

Comment: sure, it's a post from a jquery ajax method. Now Posted above

Comment: hm... only thing i can see in your ajax code is the +iod in the url. Which the iod could be the same value as the $id but still can't see where you are putting the value in the $id tho

Comment: Try looking back in the edit. Just loaded up the slim php Application call we use to get +oid into id

Comment: Your jQuery must be doing something really wrong.

Comment: OMG... why are you not using parameters!?!?! You are even using prepare... this is insane.

Comment: try `$id = intval($id)` before the `$sql = ...` statement. The bug is most likely on clientside.

Comment: Yeah, that did not work. I appreciate the offer. But I think it might be server side because the ID goes through and is used but at the end of the statement there's a null that is not attached to the number. I've checked.

Comment: I recommend you add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` as very first line of your code. Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the issue upon lots of testing and research was a lot simpler than I had thought. It turns out for some reason in this api piece we were still actively echoing the SQL in addition to the answer. Causing it to return with an http response of 200. That was the issue the whole stinking time. I commented out the echo $sql Command and it now works exactly like it was supposed to across the board. I am terribly sorry for wasting every body's time with what was an extremely obvious solution in retrospect.